# Remove item from IQueryable from List

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have 2 tables in my database `Products` and `PremiumProducts` for an ASP Net application.

I retrieve products with a simple query

```
IQueryable<Product> query = from p in myDataContext.Products select p;
```

I have a List of `PremiumProducts` (which contains the ID of a `Product`). I am attempting to remove the IDs in the `PremiumProducts` list from the query above but not sure if there is a simple way or if i need to convert all the `PremiumProducts` to a `Product` first? I attempted this

```
List<PremiumProducts> premiumProducts;

query = from p in query where (premiumProducts.Contains(p.ID)) select p;
```

but of course this brings back all sorts of casting errors.

Is there a simple way to remove the `PremiumProducts` from the `query` above or do i need to convert the `PremiumProducts` to a `Product`, store the ID and then attempt to remove the query with these IDs?

Comment: The IQueryable interface inherits the IEnumerable interface so that if it represents a query, the results of that query can be enumerated. Enumeration causes the expression tree associated with an IQueryable object to be executed. So you have to convert ```IQueryable<Product>``` to ```List<PremiumProducts>```

Comment: Are you trying to exclude the IDs that are in a *specific* `List<PremiumProduct>` **or** are you trying to exclude all (or part) of the IDs surfaced via  `myDataContext.PremiumProducts` (which you've not shown exists but have alluded to)?

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 - I am attempting to EXCLUDE ALL IDs that are present in PremiumProducts List that are found in the 'query'. Query returns 'all products' and i want to remove all PremiumProducts from the query that contains all products - hopefully this is a little clearer?

Comment: Is it really LINQ to SQL?

Comment: If you want to remove products that are in the premium products, why did you contains? Surely the logic is not contains? And also premium products is a list of OremiumProduct not a list of int/guid/whatever ID is, so you can't pass a simple type to Contains, you have to pass a premium product

Comment: I think it would look more like `myDataContext.Products.Where(p => !myDataContext.PremiumProducts.Any(pp => p.ID == pp.ProductId))`

Comment: `var results = from p in query where (!premiumProducts.Select(z => z.ID).Contains(p.ID)) select p;`

Comment: @mjwills - think this did the trick (im testing). Feel free to propose this as the answer an i will accept if all works. I felt this was the closest to my original code and learnt what i was missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than:

```
query = from p in query where (premiumProducts.Contains(p.ID)) select p;
```

I would suggest:

```
query = from p in query where (!premiumProducts.Select(z => z.ID).Contains(p.ID)) select p;
```

The key differences:

1. Using `!` (since you want to *exclude* those that are in
   `premiumProducts`).
2. Using `premiumProducts.Select(z => z.ID)` to
   ensure that the contains is against the `ID` not the object (just
   avoiding your casting issues).